# Why isn't particle hair more popular in games?

Tags: graphics, particles

Blender 2.80 introduced EEVEE, a new realtime renderer, and after interacting with it for a while I was impressed by how well it handles particle hair in terms of performance and visuals. It even manages to reflect light through SSR.

[image: sphere with a particle hair system applied in Blender]

<sup>Sphere with 200 parent hair particles, 50 child particles per parent</sup>

Blender isn't a game and they probably have different concerns and priorities regarding the performance of the application, so this might be a good reason not to see this being implemented in games right now but still, seeing how well EEVEE manages it and also knowing that games have user-customizable graphic settings, I don't understand why [we're still using planes with textures and other techniques like that as our best effort for realtime graphics in games](https://youtu.be/D1iNSyvIPaY?t=1395).

Of course having one million strands makes even Blender struggle to keep a reasonable framerate, but a game probably wouldn't need such a dense hair to look convincing and could cheat by having baked hair textures on the scalp in case gaps become visible close-up.

A friend of mine has said Nvidia HairWorks accomplishes just this, but looking at some screenshots I doubt that's the case (if it is, then maybe the technology has evolved a lot lately and nvidia has some catch up to do? I don't know but from what I've seen it doesn't look that good).

So, why isn't particle hair more popular in games?

Comment: I think you're right. After reviewing similar questions with another mod, I think I jumped the gun in putting the question on hold. Thanks for bringing this to our attention — we've re-opened it for answers. **For those composing an answer: please ensure you include relevant facts to ground any speculation.**

Comment: [Example in Super Mario Galaxy](https://youtu.be/hgnrfpP3J-c?t=548)

Comment: That looks like a technique called "fins and shells" (though with just the shells, no fins), not particle hair, @Theraot.